# Replace deep child object, while keeping state immutable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I'm new to react and redux. I have an object is an array of child objects, which contain arrays

```
const initialState = {
    sum: 0,
    denomGroups: [
        {
            coins: [
                { name: 'Penny', namePlural: 'Pennies', label: '1¢', value: .01, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Nickel', namePlural: 'Nickels', label: '5¢', value: .05, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Dime', namePlural: 'Dimes', label: '10¢', value: .10, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Quarter', namePlural: 'Quarters', label: '25¢', value: .25, sum: 0 }
            ]
        },
        {
            bills: [
                { name: 'Dollar', namePlural: 'Dollars', label: '$1', value: 1, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Five', namePlural: 'Fives', label: '$5', value: 5, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Ten', namePlural: 'Tens', label: '$10', value: 10, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Twenty', namePlural: 'Twentys', label: '$20', value: 20, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Fifty', namePlural: 'Fiftys', label: '$50', value: 50, sum: 0 },
                { name: 'Hundred', namePlural: 'Hundreds', label: '$100', value: 100, sum: 0 }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I have an action that gets passed a value and the name of the denomination

```
export function increaseSum(value, denom) {
    return { type: types.ADD_TO_SUM, value: value, denom: denom }
}
```

Inside of my reducer I wrote a helper class to identify where this denomination is within the object:

```
function findDenomination(denoms, action) {
    let denomMap = {},
        currentDenom = {};
    for (let i = 0; denoms.length >= i + 1; i++) {
        let denomGroup = denoms[Object.keys(denoms)[i]];
        for (var key in denomGroup) {
            if (!currentDenom.length) {
                currentDenom = denomGroup[key].filter(x => x.name === action.denom);
                if (currentDenom.length > 0) {
                    denomMap.group = i;
                    denomMap.key = key;
                    denomMap.index = denomGroup[key].findIndex(x => x.name === action.denom);
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentDenom.length > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return denomMap;
}
```

And within the reducer itself I am using `Object.assign` to make a deep copy of the denomGroups, in a way that I would think keeps it immutable.

```
function countableItems(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_TO_SUM:
            let denomMap = findDenomination(state.denomGroups, action);
            state.denomGroups = Object.assign({}, state.denomGroups, state.denomGroups[denomMap.group][denomMap.key][denomMap.index].sum = parseFloat(action.value));
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Is it clear to anyone why this is getting flagged with the error: `A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch`

Comment: You're modifying state: `state.denomGroups = ...`

Comment: `return Object.assign({}, state, state.denomGroups[denomMap.group][denomMap.key][denomMap.index].sum = parseFloat(action.value));` still throws a mutation error

Comment: `state.denomGroups[denomMap.group][denomMap.key][denomMap.ind‌​ex].sum = parseFloat(action.value)` is still a state mutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempted to mutate an immutable. Hence the error.

The whole point of immutables is that an immutable should never ever change anywhere inside of it after it's create. That's why all functions that change it create a new instance of an immutable. If you try to change something deep inside an immutable, that's still a mutation, and thus bad.

This ensures you can just check the objects themselves for equality instead of having to do a deep check, as well as ensuring data integrity.

What you should be doing is just mutating it (if you're using the `immutables` library, you can use `setIn`), which will create a new Map. You can call that just on `state`.

Something like this:

```
case types.ADD_TO_SUM:
    const denomMap = findDenomination(state.denomGroups, action);
    return state.setIn(['denomGroup', denomGroup.key, denomGroup.index, sum], parseFloat(action.value));
```

Comment: Do you tend to always use `immutables` library?

Comment: While a full answer is more room than I have here, in short, I try to for certain things, like the Redux state. The big perk is that if you have an immutable for data, when you pass it to a `React.PureComponent`, it can reliably determine (without needing a deep check) if the object changed and if it needs to re-render or not.